# How to update JSON object with particular condition

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, javascript-objects

I have two JSON files, the 1st is `origin.json` and the 2nd is `newData.json`.

I want to update the child value of `Origin` based on `NewData`, but the update must affect only the items that exist in `userAgents` of `newData.json`.

The following code showcases the data I need to transform:

```
var originData = {
    "userAgents": [
        "Chrome",
        "Safari"
    ],
    "tests": [
        {
            "name": "a",
            "errs": []
        },
        {
            "name": "b",
            "errs": [
                {
                    "userAgent": "Chrome"
                },
                {
                    "userAgent": "Safari"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};

var newData = {
    "userAgents": [
        "Chrome"
    ],
    "tests": [
        {
            "name": "a",
            "errs": []
        },
        {
            "name": "b",
            "errs": []
        }
    ]
};

originData.tests.forEach(function (originItem) {
    newData.tests.forEach(function (newItem) {
        if (newItem.name === originItem.name) {
            originItem.errs = newItem.errs
        }
    })


});


console.log(originData);
```

in this case the result is this:

```
{
    "userAgents": [
        "Chrome",
        "Safari"
    ],
    "tests": [
        {
            "name": "a",
            "errs": []
        },
        {
            "name": "b",
            "errs": []
        }
    ]
}
```

but this result is wrong,  the correct result should be like this:

```
{
    "userAgents": [
        "Chrome",
        "Safari"
    ],
    "tests": [
        {
            "name": "a",
            "errs": []
        },
        {
            "name": "b",
            "errs": [
                {
                    "userAgent": "Safari"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Do you have any idea how to get this result by using Node.js?

Comment: [You can't](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code:

```js
const originData = {
  "userAgents": [
      "Chrome",
      "Safari"
  ],
  "tests": [
    {
      "name": "a",
      "errs": []
    },
    {
      "name": "b",
      "errs": [
        {
          "userAgent": "Chrome"
        },
        {
          "userAgent": "Safari"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

const newData = {
  "userAgents": [
      "Chrome"
  ],
  "tests": [
    {
      "name": "a",
      "errs": []
    },
    {
      "name": "b",
      "errs": [
        {
          "userAgent": "Safari"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

originData.tests.forEach(originItem => {
  const newEl = newData.tests.find(ne => ne.name === originItem.name);
  originItem.errs = originItem.errs.filter(e => newData.userAgents.includes(e.userAgent) || (newEl && -1 !== newEl.errs.findIndex(nee => nee.userAgent === e.userAgent)));
});


console.log(originData);
```

Comment: this script is not have correct result when on `newData` i  put the array of  ` [{"userAgent": "Chrome"}]` for 'errs', in this case the result should contains Chrome and Safari on errs array

Comment: and also here the result should be `"errs": [
                {
                    "userAgent": "Safari"
                }
            ]`

Answer (score 0):

Is it ok for you to use some external module?
For instance it is possible with lodash module https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#merge

*(btw: there are a lot of similar libs in npm https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=deep%20merge)*

Answer (score 0):

```js
var originData = {
  "userAgents": [
      "Chrome",
      "Safari"
  ],
  "tests": [
      {
          "name": "a",
          "errs": []
      },
      {
          "name": "b",
          "errs": [
              {
                  "userAgent": "Chrome"
              },
              {
                  "userAgent": "Safari"
              }
          ]
      }
  ]
};

var newData = {
  "userAgents": [
      "Chrome"
  ],
  "tests": [
      {
          "name": "a",
          "errs": []
      },
      {
          "name": "b",
          "errs": [
            {"userAgent": "Chrome"}
          ]
      }
  ]
};

originData.tests.forEach(originItem => {
  originItem.errs = originItem.errs.filter(e => (newData.userAgents.indexOf(e.userAgent) < 0 ));
});

newData.tests.forEach( newDataItem => {
  let originDataItem = originData.tests.filter(obj=>obj.name===newDataItem.name)
  newDataItem.errs.forEach( err => {
    originDataItem[0].errs.push( err )
  })
})


console.log(originData);
```

Comment: actually if the errs on `newData` is `[{"userAgent": "Chrome"}]` the result array is still the `safari` which should be `"errs": [
                {
                    "userAgent": "Chrome"
                },
                {
                    "userAgent": "Safari"
                }
            ]`